# Size of partitions

Tags: partitioning

So I've decided to install Ubuntu 14.04 , which I will use alongside Mac OS X and Windows. My plan was to install Ubuntu on a USB 3.0 external HDD. So far the installation is going fine, but now I need to set partitions for different sections of Ubuntu, which are Swap, /, /home and /boot.

I have reserved 70 GB of free space on the external HDD to install Ubuntu. It's just to experiment with, I will not be installing loads of files on it. Now I am wondering what sizes each partition will have to be. Using Windows and Mac OS X, you just press format and you can chuck the OS in the partition. This is a bit more advanced and I want to make sure I don't mess up. I am told for Swap it is recommended to do 1.5 to 2 times the size of your RAM.

I have 8 GB of RAM in my laptop, so how should I distribute the 70 GB over these four partitions?

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For swap, with that amount of ram, just use 8gb for hibernation as the swap partition, you don't need more. For /, use ~30gb, and the rest as home, but you could also just partition 62 as / and not have a separate /home partition, and just not have to deal with it. That you need 2 times your ram for swap is a relic from the day that computers routinely had less than 2gb or ram, for 2-4gb it should be ~1.5 times the ram, but anything over 4 it can be the same if not less if you do not plan on going into hibernation

Comment: Note: `/home` is where your user files would be stored, so you can pretty much make as big or small as you like. `/` is where the stuff for the system is stored, so if you want to try out loads of programs, you want to make this fairly big. Swap is for when the RAM is full, or when the computer is hibernated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did notice /boot is missing from your answer though, is that not required nowadays?

Comment: the boot partition can many times be integrated into the main partition, and is by default on ubuntu. The mbr simply has instructions in it to hand off control to a file in the root of the partition and that triggers files in the boot partition

Comment: So, when installing Ubuntu, how much should I give to /boot?

Comment: 300-600mb I think so long as you are only installing a max of about 4 installations with different kernels, but I usually just use a boot partition that is mounted on the / partition

Comment: but to answer your previous question, the boot partition does not need to really be manually configured for a normal user